# Selecting rows from a pandas dataframe that match a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two unequal pandas data frames df and df1.
df looks like this:

| Chr | Start | End | Freq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr1 | 1 | 1000 | 0.05 |
| chr2 | 4500 | 5780 | 0.0099 |
| chr2 | 5700 | 6540 | 1.3 |

df1 looks like this:

| Chr | Start-500 | Start+500 | End-500 | End+500 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr1 | -499 | 501 | 500 | 1500 |
| chr2 | 4000 | 5000 | 5280 | 5280 |
| chr2 | 5200 | 6200 | 6040 | 7040 |

What I want to do is if:
-`df['chr']==df1['chr']` and
-`df['Start]` is in between `df1['Start-500]` and `df1['Start+500']` and
-`df['End']` is between `df1['End-500']` and `df1["End+500']`
then add the `Freq` to `df1`.

Please if any one can help me that would be great. Thank you

Comment: What's the point of start-500 and start+500 and asking whether something is between these two values when you seem to derive them from `start` itself, making it always true in practice?

Comment: Yes that is what was given to me. Somehow that is always true in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Since your "Start-500", "Start+500" is simply based on the "Start" column (and similarly for "End"), you can simply use `pandas.merge_asof`:

```
df1["Freq"] = pd.merge_asof(df1, df, left_on="Start+500", right_on="Start")["Freq"]

>>> df1
    Chr  Start-500  Start+500  End-500  End+500    Freq
0  chr1       -499        501      500     1500  0.0500
1  chr2       4000       5000     5280     5280  0.0099
2  chr2       5200       6200     6040     7040  1.3000
```

Comment: Hi, does it have to be an exact match on the column for merge_asof?

Comment: No. It matches to the nearest key. You can change this to match on a key less than/greater than by modifying the "direction" param. See the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html).